# Specifying column heights in Google Charts Histogram

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to draw a `Google Charts Histogram` with two columns.

`x`-axis consists of some value between 0 and 1.

For each `x` value, there is a corresponding `y` value for each of the two columns.

`y` is the number of people, and it's usually a very large number.

I want the histogram to look like the second example in
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#Example3

However, they only show examples in which one row in data array represents one `y` value, and I cannot do this for my data, because `y` is very large.

For example, if `y` value is 100,000, I have to add 100,000 columns, and this is a waste of resources.

I considered using a `column chart`, but the position of `x`-axis labels are not proportional to `x` values. A `histogram` looks better for this data too.

See http://jsfiddle.net/y755h/ for the column chart.

Is there any way I can specify `y` values like 100,000, or 500,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Histogram chart by its nature cannot do what you want - the chart you need is a ColumnChart.

The x-axis values in the ColumnChart are not proportional only because you are using a "string" type domain column.  If you use a "number" type, they will be proportional:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'score');
data.addColumn('number', '1');
data.addColumn('number', '2');
data.addRows([
    [0.04, 663837, 697079],
    [0.2, 364954, 331866],
    [0.3, 117247, 106683],
    [0.33, 89434, 81420],
    [0.38, 59581, 54221],
    [0.44, 38583, 35271]
]);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/y755h/1/